# Lotus Approach Replacement

Tags: database, architecture, rdbms, lotus

What is Lotus Approach and what can you compare it to to help my understanding? I am struggling to find information/demos on Lotus Approach.

Do users have a user-friendly interface to insert/update/delete data. Do they have basic reporting capabilities? \

I am working on gathering specific requirements, but a general list of similar comparisons would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to depend a great deal on what features of Approach that you used, but Microsoft Access is the most obvious analogy in terms of traditional desktop software that is still supported.

Moving up from desktop software to a shared database system, however, is probably preferable given that you say you have hundreds of reports. That opens up many more possibilities and is far too large a topic to explore here on StackOverflow. If your data is already in a shared database and you are already just using Approach as a reporting tool, then again there are far too many choices for this topic to be a useful discussion on StackOverflow.

The only reason I haven't voted to close as "Too broad" is that you may be using Approach as a desktop tool only, and may just want to stay that way, in which case see my first paragraph.

Comment: Thank you @Richard Schwartz, you have pointed me in the right direction and helped me better understand Lotus Approach. I agree that my question is very broad, next time I will gather requirements first. Thanks!